# Terminal Application to Keep Web Server Process Alive

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

Is there an app that can, given a command and options, execute for the lifetime of the process and ping a given URL indefinitely on a specific interval?

If not, could this be done on the terminal as a `bash script`? I'm almost positive it's doable through terminal, but am not fluent enough to whip it up within a few minutes.

---

Found [this post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/) that has a portion of the solution, minus the `ping` bits. `ping` runs on linux, indefinitely; until it's actively killed. How would I kill it from bash after say, two pings?

Comment: Are you familiar with `while` loops and how to `sleep` in a program/script?

Comment: yes, javascript `setInterval` \ `setTimeout` and `c#`'s `Thread.Sleep` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General Script

As others have suggested, use this in pseudo code:

1. execute command and save `PID`
2. while `PID` is active, ping and sleep
3. exit

This results in following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# execute command, use '&' at the end to run in background
<command here> &

# store pid
pid=$!

while ps | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep $pid; do
    ping <address here>
    sleep <timeout here in seconds>
done
```

Note that the stuff inside `<>` should be replaces with actual stuff. Be it a command or an ip address.

## Break from Loop

To answer your second question, that depends in the loop. In the loop above, simply track the loop count using a variable. To do that, add a `((count++))` inside the loop. And do this: `[[ $count -eq 2 ]] && break`. Now the loop will break when we're pinging for a second time.

Something like this:

```
...
while ...; do
    ...
    ((count++))
    [[ $count -eq 2 ]] && break
done
```

## ping twice

To ping only a few times, use the `-c` option:

```
ping -c <count here> <address here>
```

Example:

```
ping -c 2 www.google.com
```

Use `man ping` for more information.

## Better practice

As [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318) noted in a comment below, the current solution may not suffice to solve the problem. While answering the question, the core problem will still persist. To aid to that problem, a [cron](/questions/tagged/cron) job is suggested in which a simple [wget](/questions/tagged/wget) or [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) http request is sent periodically. This results in a fairly easy script containing but one line:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl <address here> > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This script can be added as a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Leave a comment if you desire more information how to set such a scheduled job. Special thanks to [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318) for analyzing the problem and suggesting a sound solution.

Comment: when I execute `ping [host]` from terminal, it executes indefinitely. i only want it to execute once (or twice), then stop for the entire length of the sleep command. how would you "stop" the `ping`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this script?

Comment: @hek2mgl keep a particular server's web process active. prevent it from "sleeping"

Comment: @culturalanomoly Please elaborate.. I've the strong opinion that you are doing something really wrong. (And two guys helped you to do wrong - the right way.)

Comment: @hek2mgl there's a server where i've hosted an application. i want to, from a different machine (say my laptop), keep that website "alive." i believe a `ping` to said url every 30 minutes, should suffice. i know this may not be the "best" solution. but, given it's shortcomings, it'll suffice for what i need it for ...

Comment: Why should the website die?

Comment: @culturalanomoly For only a few pings, use `ping -c <count>`. See my answer.

Comment: @hek2mgl if there are no requests, within a certain amount of time, the processes memory is collected and used for other applications on the farm. however, if the site is receiving activity, it'll "stay alive/active"

Comment: And how does `ping` help here? `ping` does not produce `http` traffic. Simply do the `wget` in a cronjob and you are done. Better would be to configure your "farm" in a way that it keeps the website simply alive.

Comment: @hek2mgl i figured the same but wasn't sure. i know `ping` is a `UDP` request and that its protocol likely used a port different from `:80`. though, it should still work, no?

Comment: ping is an ICMP request. It does not use any port number

Comment: @culturalanomoly That depends what makes the server die, if any incoming request prevents it from dying then this will work. If not do a  [tag:cron] job with [tag:wget] or [tag:curl] as hek2mgl suggested. - I will elaborate on this in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to start a download with `wget` and while it is running, ping the url:

```
wget http://example.com/large_file.tgz & #put in background
pid=$!
while kill -s 0 $pid #test if process is running
do
    ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 #ping your adress once
    sleep 5 #and sleep for 5 seconds
done
```

Comment: That makes no sense. Why would you do that?

Comment: I would strongly advise to use the `PID`, stored in `$!` and not the name of the command. As this will fail using pipes.

Comment: Much better, I like your approach using `kill`!

Comment: @L3viathan What is the purpose of this script?

Comment: @hek2mgl What do you mean? The use case of pinging a url while downloading? No idea, just didn't have a better one.

Comment: Yes, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: I just wanted to put a command there instead of a placeholder. Look at it as a placeholder.

Comment: When the host is down, ping will hang forever. (Under most circumstances). Wget is already producing traffic from that server - so why the ping in a loop?

Comment: @hek2mgl Why do you keep asking what the purpose is of this script, you should ask the OP in a comment on his question. The purpose of this script is answering the OP's question and providing functionality that he/she required.

Answer (score 2):

A nice little generic utility for this is [Daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/). Its relevant options:

```
Usage: daemonize [OPTIONS] path [arg] ...

-c <dir>       # Set daemon's working directory to <dir>.
-E var=value   # Pass environment setting to daemon. May appear multiple times.
-p <pidfile>   # Save PID to <pidfile>.
-u <user>      # Run daemon as user <user>. Requires invocation as root.
-l <lockfile>  # Single-instance checking using lockfile <lockfile>.
```

Here's an example of starting/killing in use: [flickd](https://github.com/MicahElliott/flickpapr/blob/master/flickd)

To get more sophisticated, you could turn your ping script into a [systemd service](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html), now standard on many recent Linuxes.